# Bootstrap modal not showing after using the pagination from the datatable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using Bootstrap 3 and Data Table 1.9. Modal is open when i click the anchor tag in the first page of the data table but I have a problem on showing Bootstrap modal after use the Data table Pagination. How to Resolve this.
Here is my code

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <table id=prodlist class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td> <a href="http://localhost/admin/product/viewProduct/15" class="prod-view" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <a href="http://localhost/admin/product/viewProduct/15" class="prod-view" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a>
               </td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <a href="http://localhost/admin/product/viewProduct/15" class="prod-view" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a>
               </td> </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

my javascript for datatable is

```js
$(function() {
    $("#prodlist").dataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "aTargets": [0],
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
            "bVisible": true
        }, ]
    });
});
if ($(".alert-success, .alert-error").length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert-success, .alert-error").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".prod-view").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $( ".modal-body" ).load( href );
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
});
});
```

Comment: You are certainly not showing your real code. The malformed markup would never produce a dataTable with working modals.

Comment: i am using php and Mysql.Here i have showing only 3 rows in the table , but actually i have fetch the records from MySQL and displayed in to the table. I am facing the problem only in the second page of the dataTable. I think the problem is related to the DOM

Comment: Since bootstrap modals not are opt-in, then they should work on page #2 etc too. I made a test with your code above and modals showed up on all pages without any problems. It would be another story if you activated the modals by code, but that you are not doing.

Comment: i have tried with another example also, this is also not working. Can you please post your code here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you by `$(".prod-view").click()` only initialises visible content, i.e the rows on page #1. dataTables injects and removes table rows to and from the DOM in order to show pages. So you must use a delegated event handler instead :

```js
$("#prodlist").on("click", ".prod-view", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $( ".modal-body" ).load( href );
    $('#myModal').modal('show') //<-- you should use show in this situation
});
```

---

But as suggested in comment, modals are not opt-in, you dont have to open them programmatically. As long as you have

```
<a href="#" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">edit</a>
```

and a `#modal` on the page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">This is a modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>modal</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal will be initialised automatically, on all pages. See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9p5uq7h3/**

If your only concern is the content of the modal, then simply

```
$('body').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   $(".modal-body").load(url/to/modal/template);
});
```